Unable to read file in Databricks with Pandas Errror: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/ge_selection.csv'
I have upload a file called ge_selection.csv to '/FileStore/tables/' in Databricks community edition.
When I run the following code the contents of the .csv is displayed:
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/ge_selection.csv"
file_type = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema = "false"
first_row_is_header = "false"
delimiter = ","

# The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)

However, when I try to read the same file with Pandas I get the error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/ge_selection.csv'

Trying both the following methods:
import pandas as pd

df_ge = pd.read_csv(file_location)

df_ge = pd.read_csv("/FileStore/tables/ge_selection.csv")

Any thoughts on why I'm not able to read the file with Pandas?

are you using Azure databricks?

@DileepRajNarayanThumula, I'm using Databricks community edition.

You just need to use dbfs with the path
file_location = "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/ge_selection.csv"
